# Получение данных после группировки mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

Имеем БД типа:

```
id  name   type
1   first  type1
2   first  type2
3   second type1
```

Запрос в бд

```
$qr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `base` GROUP by `name`")
          or die(mysql_error());
```

После группировки необходимо вывести данные следующим способом:

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr)){
echo'Имя: '.$data[name].'';
echo'Тип:'.$data[type].'';
}
```

в строке тип необходимо перечислить все варианты строки type из mysql, где одинаковая строка name, но т.к. была группировка мне выдаст только один результат, а как отобразить все?

Comment: Как вариант - не делайте запрос с `group by`, а просто в `php` обработайте массив так как вам нужно (сгруппировав по имени, например), и выводите.

Comment: длинновато выйдет, думаю есть варианты обыграть через group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type) types, name FROM base GROUP BY name

В столбце types хранится строка, которая содержит все типы разделенные через запятую по данному имени